# how to set cross-platform path in application in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, path, cross-platform

As in title, I want to devlope my spring-boot project both in linux and windows. I want to set a path in application.properties which I use globally, but it can only work on either linux or windows as / and \ present. thank if anyone could help otherwise tell me what's the hack to set such a const in springboot

I've trying to find answer on google and springboot doc but got no answer

i hope someone could solve my problem or give any alternative solution